# Can't get correct django form from template

Tags: django, django-forms

please help to understand which one fomr model I should use on my case.

I have the next form in HTML template :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form id="developersform" action="#" method="post">
        <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_developers[]">
            <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
            <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
             <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
             <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
             <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
             <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
             <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
             <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Submit data</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

It's looks like 
[image]

View is not working due form issue:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ManagmentUsersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            picked = form.cleaned_data.get('duallistbox_guests')
            print(picked)
        else:
            form = ManagmentUsersForm()
            print(form.errors)
```

How I should specify form on Django? Could someone help with example
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create the form that has drop-down make a proper model that have foreign key relation or Many-to-many relation or something else. Use those fields here.

```
class  ManagmentUsersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YOUR_MODEL
        fields = [ 'duallistbox_guests'] #fields you want from your model
```

In your views, you can grab this data and do whatever you want to do with it.

```
def YOUR_VIEW(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:

            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form =  ManagmentUsersForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():



           topic  = form.cleaned_data.get("topic")
          #grab your fields like this
           user = request.user

           YOUR_MODEL.objects.create(
                User = request.user, 
                topic=topic,
               #save them like this or do anything else
               )

           return redirect('SOMEWHERE') #successful
else:
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:

        return redirect('login')
    else:
        form =  ManagmentUsersForm()
return render(request, 'YOUR_TEMPLATE', {'form': form})
```

Your HTML form will be like this

```
 <form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %} 
        {{form.as_p}}

        <input type = "submit" id="submit-question">

 </form>
```